# Is Core Data what I'm looking for?

Tags: core-data, ios7

I'm very new to ios development in general, all of my experience is in php and MySQL. After doing a bit of research on the best way to save the players game, in my app, I'm thinking core data is the way to go. Or the game could save to my own server.

Thinking in terms of playing an RPG where as soon as you get a new weapon, your game needs to remember that so when you log back in, you still have that weapon.

Am I on the right track in thinking core data is the way to go with this? Also, ideas on implementation would be great! (Does it save to db on every button click right after new item is found? Does it just run a save script every 30 seconds?)

Thanks guys! Sorry for such a basic noob question, it's hard to find documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you are relatively new to iOS and if the data storage needs aren't very intense, I might steer you away from Core Data.  (About 80% of the apps I've shipped use Core Data for the object graph persistence; but even Apple's documentation on Core Data mentions that it's not an entry-level technology on the platform.)

Without knowing the complexity and intensity of your data persistence needs, it's hard to be definitive; but just serializing/deserializing your object graph to and from disk might make the best sense.  Your model objects will need to adopt the `NSCoding` protocol.

I'm not sure you would need to save your object graph to disk with every new found item, or every *n* seconds.  You'll want to archive and save at key points in the application life cycle, e.g. when the application goes to the background.  But if you're designing a game, perhaps you'll need discrete save points, allow the user to designate a save point.  That's something that is less dependent on how you persist the object graph than on how you choose to design it in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much! I doubt I have a real need for core data in this case, I'm going to have research how to serialize the object graph to disk and study up on NSCoding.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I think [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) would probably be the easiest way to go.

```
  NSArray *weapons = @[@"Machine Gun",@"Hand Gun"];
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setObject:weapons forKey:@"weapons"];
```

And retrieve data like this

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    _weapons = [defaults objectForKey:@"weapons"];
```

The only thing to bare in mind is that the objects can only be NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.

Comment: Thank you for the specific example! This is great information, I feel like this is more obtainable with my basic skills than the other options I've looked into.